# c# - datatable if one field is null set another value

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a Datatable.

```
using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
{
    da.Fill(ds);
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

The `dt`, return list of data like this,

[image]

From this image, when UserId is DBnull then I want to set docCount equl to 0. How can I do that?

Comment: You can set the default value from sql query too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
dt = ds.Tables[0];
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   if(row["userId"] == DBNull.Value)
   {
       row["docCount"] = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: You should DBNull.Value instead of null